# Faster way of removing data points that match filter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance

I have a DataFrame of about 500.000 rows, containing radar data points.
I need to exclude military flights, so far only discoverable by their callsign.
The code below takes about 30 seconds for one day of radar data, which is okay for now, but a bit of a time eater for processing a large number of days (e.g. a year).
Would there be a faster way of processing?

```
tic = time.perf_counter()

before = len(df1)
print('Removing military flights...', end = ' ')
mil_callsigns = ['ALPHA', 'ANGEL', 'ANGRY', 'ANVIL', 'ARCHER', 'ARROW', 'AVENGER', 'AZTEC', 'BAF', 'BALLS', 'BASIC', 
                 'BEAST', 'BEAVER', 'BLACK', 'BLADE', 'BOLT', 'BONZO', 'BULDG', 'BULLET', 'BURST', 'COBRA', 'COWBOY', 
                 'CRACK', 'DAF', 'DAWG', 'DEVIL', 'EAGLE', 'EPIC', 'EVIL', 'FIST', 'FLAME', 'FLNKR', 'GHOST', 'GRZLY', 
                 'HAF', 'IGOR', 'IVAN', 'JEDI', 'KILLER', 'KILLR', 'KING', 'LION', 'MACE', 'METAL', 'MIG', 
                 'NAF', 'NOW', 'PAIN', 'POLLY', 'REBEL', 'REDSKIN', 'SAW', 'SHARK', 'SLAMMR', 'SLMMR', 'SNAKE', 'STING', 
                 'TIGER', 'VIPER', 'VOODO', 'WARP', 'WILDCAT']

for c_sgn in mil_callsigns:
    df1 = df1[~df1['CALLSIGN'].str.contains(c_sgn)]

toc = time.perf_counter()
print('In', round(toc-tic, 1), 'seconds', before - len(df1), 'points from assumed military callsigns were removed')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
mil_callsigns = ['ALPHA', 'ANGEL', 'ANGRY', 'ANVIL', 'ARCHER', 'ARROW', 'AVENGER', 'AZTEC', 'BAF', 'BALLS', 'BASIC', 
                 'BEAST', 'BEAVER', 'BLACK', 'BLADE', 'BOLT', 'BONZO', 'BULDG', 'BULLET', 'BURST', 'COBRA', 'COWBOY', 
                 'CRACK', 'DAF', 'DAWG', 'DEVIL', 'EAGLE', 'EPIC', 'EVIL', 'FIST', 'FLAME', 'FLNKR', 'GHOST', 'GRZLY', 
                 'HAF', 'IGOR', 'IVAN', 'JEDI', 'KILLER', 'KILLR', 'KING', 'LION', 'MACE', 'METAL', 'MIG', 
                 'NAF', 'NOW', 'PAIN', 'POLLY', 'REBEL', 'REDSKIN', 'SAW', 'SHARK', 'SLAMMR', 'SLMMR', 'SNAKE', 'STING', 
                 'TIGER', 'VIPER', 'VOODO', 'WARP', 'WILDCAT']

df1 = df1[~df1['CALLSIGN'].str.contains('|'.join(mil_callsigns))]
```

Comment: Should be `'|'.join(mil_callsigns)`.

Comment: Did not know about the "join" statement. That reduced execution time to 1.2 seconds... Brilliant, many thanks.

Comment: Thanks RJ Adriaansen